# CSS Overflowing invisible Navigation - prevent Overflow

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of creating a responsive navigation, however I am having the problem that the "sliding out" part always creates double the display width.

Here is a snippet as an example:
https://codepen.io/ChickenCat/pen/mdOEprb

```js
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar .logo img {
  height: 56px;
}
.navbar .icon-menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

/** Media Queries **/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 56px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar .logo img {
    height: unset;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .page {
    padding-left: 56px;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .navbar {
    padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  }
  .navbar .links-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #181818;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 56px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar .links-end {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .icon-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.open .links-center {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }

  .page {
    padding-top: calc(56px + 1rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo"><img src="https://placem.at/people?w=56&h=56"></div>
        <div class="links-center">
            Center Links</div>
        <div class="links-end">
            End Links
        </div>
        <div class="icon-menu">
            <i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">This is the page</div>
```

Specifically, this is about the mobile view (for testing, I used the dimensions from the iPhone X).

When the burger menu is closed, the navigation slides to "left: 100%", so it slides out of the screen.

If I change the width to 0 for the closed state, only half of the navigation is displayed in the open state.
However, I don't want to work with a fixed width here so that the page remains largely responsive, so overflow: hidden also falls out.

Is there a nice best practice solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope, this will solve your problem

```js
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar .logo img {
  height: 56px;
}
.navbar .icon-menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

/** Media Queries **/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 56px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar .logo img {
    height: unset;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .page {
    padding-left: 56px;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .navbar {
    padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  }
  .navbar .links-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #181818;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 56px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 56px;
    width: 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .navbar .links-end {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .icon-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.open .links-center {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }

  .page {
    padding-top: calc(56px + 1rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo"><img src="https://placem.at/people?w=56&h=56"></div>
        <div class="links-center">
            Center Links</div>
        <div class="links-end">
            End Links
        </div>
        <div class="icon-menu">
            <i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">This is the page</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

```
html, body{ margin: 0;  overflow:auto;}
//Dimensions
$navbar_left_width: 56px;
$navbar_top_height: 56px;
$bg-navbar: rgb(24, 24, 24);
//Media Breakpoints 
$xs_up: 0;
$sm_up: 576px;
$md_up: 768px;
$lg_up: 992px;
$xl_up: 1200px;
$xs_down: 0;
$sm_down: 575px;
$md_down: 767px;
$lg_down: 991px;
$xl_down: 1199px;
//General Navbar Settings
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: $bg-navbar;
    width: 100%;
    height: $navbar_top_height;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    .logo {
        img {
            height: $navbar_top_height;
        }
    }
    .icon-menu {
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.page {
    padding-top: 1rem;
}


/** Media Queries **/

//--> Only Desktop View
@media (min-width: $md_up) {
    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: $navbar_left_width;
        flex-direction: column;
        .logo {
            img {
                height: unset;
                max-width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
    //Adjust page container
    .page {
        padding-left: $navbar_left_width;
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }
}

//--> Only Mobile View
@media (max-width: $sm_down) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
        .links-center {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            background-color: $bg-navbar;
            pointer-events: none;
            top: $navbar_top_height;
            white-space: nowrap;
            height: $navbar_top_height;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 50px;
            transform: translate3d(100vw, 0, 0);
         
          
        }
        .links-end {
            display: none;
        }
        .icon-menu {
            display: block;
        }
        &.open {
            .links-center {
                display:block;
                pointer-events: all;
                position: absolute;
                transform: translate3d(0vw, 0, 0);
                

            }
        }
    }
    //Adjust page container
    .page {
        padding-top: calc(#{$navbar_top_height} + 1rem);
    }
}
```